# PHP CLI in Aptana Studio 3 Terminal

Tags: php, ide, aptana

I think Aptana Studio 3 is a awesome web IDE (I will checkout Eclipse with addons at another time). However I use Git within the Terminal and sometimes I also need to use the PHP in a command prompt/terminal (whichever OS I'm on) and I cannot do this within the Terminal on the IDE.

Is there a way to change settings on the Aptana Terminal?

Comment: Do you have the PHP executable in your environment path?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your question right:

You can change the settings under "Preferences -> Aptana Studio -> Terminal".

For example, you can define your working directory as "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin"